# php can't open or write file despite 777 permisions

Tags: php, apache, permissions, file-permissions

My php script is unable to write a file despide 777 permission.
the file i want to write is mash.xml

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   459 May 16  2010 config.xml
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   323 May 16  2010 handler.xml
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13908 Mar 15 12:18 mash.xml
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   494 May 17  2010 media_audio.xml
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13967 Feb 15 07:40 media_effect.xml
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   312 May 16  2010 source.xml
```

i checked the following issue : 
- same user as file uploader, var_dump(get_current_user()); displays "root"

this is apache log :

```
[error] [client 155.132.8.52] PHP Warning:  
fopen(/var/www/html/moviemasher_3-1-04/example/save/media/xml/mash.xml): 
failed to open stream: 
Permission denied in /var/www/html/moviemasher_3-1-04/example/save/media/php/save.php 
on line 14
```

thanks for your help

Comment: what were the file rights before 777?

Comment: what mode are you using in fopen?  ALso, check the permission of the directory containing the file.

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan, Should it matter he has full rights the the file ?

Comment: @RobertPitt: PHP need to (internally) whether the file exists or not.. need get the list of files in that directory.

Comment: try 666, think this would be enough

Comment: thanks, it was actually SELinux problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If SELinux is enabled:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/moviemasher_3-1-04/example/save/media/xml/mash.xml"
```

Feel free to use a regex for the filename.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did: `chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "myfile.xml"`

Comment: In my case, I was having trouble with Apache trying to write a file anywhere within a directory with 777 permissions. The answer was: chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/directory"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write mash.xml like this, but I suggest you also try chown to change the ownership, eg

chown www-data:www-data mash.xml

(www-data is the user group and user id of the apache user on most linux systems).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question was asked and successfully answered over a year ago. In general, it's most helpful to answer recently asked questions... or questions that haven't received an acceptable answer.